# Write a query to display the student names and the maximum mark scored by them in any subject

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have tried using group by and getting an error message of single row function cannot return multiple values.

It has three tables to be selected student, subject and mark.

[image]

Comment: Please show us your current attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: What is your RDBMS?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only required student_id and MAX number, you can use only tables Student and Marks as below-

```
SELECT A.stident_id,MAX(B.Value) max_marks
FROM Student A
INNER JOIN Mark B ON A.Student_id = B.Student_id
GROUP BY A.stident_id
```

But if you need subject name as well, you can try this below logic-

```
SELECT AA.stident_id,AA.stident_name,
D.Subject_name,AA.max_marks
FROM
(
    SELECT A.stident_id,A.stident_name,MAX(B.Value) max_marks
    FROM Student A
    INNER JOIN Mark B ON A.Student_id = B.Student_id
    GROUP BY A.stident_id
)AA 
INNER JOIN Marks C ON AA.stident_id = C.stident_id 
AND AA.max_marks = C.Value
INNER JOIN Subject D ON C.subject_id = D.subject_id
```